# What is the standard way of plotting confusion matrix for binary classification?

Tags: classification, binary-data, confusion-matrix

I don’t understand the confusion with the matrix for Binary Classification.
I was referring different documents for this, meaning sometime I see that the confusion matrix is plotted Actual Class Vs Predicted Class and some time it is plotted as Predicted Class vs Actual Class.
So when doing this True Positive and True Negative gets switch.
So just wondering what is the standard way to plot confusion matrix.

I have attached the images which i found from various sources...

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no standard way to make a confusion matrix. Both versions you posted are correct according to their axes labels.

Comment: @JTH That looks like an answer to me!

Comment: Okay, I will promote my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way to make a confusion matrix. Both versions you posted are correct according to their axis labels